# Netbeans Keyboard Shortcut to Jump out of Quotations

Tags: netbeans, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm using Netbeans 7 and programming PHP. I was wondering if anyone knew of a keyboard shortcut to jump out of quotations marks and parenthesis (besides the right arrow key). For example I would like to type a quotation, type some text, then:

```
"my cursor would be here -> |"
```

Then hit tab or something equivalent to jump outside of the quotations:

```
"some text"| <- my cursor would now be here
```

Is this possible to accomplish using netbeans?

Comment: With most IDEs if the closing quotation mark is automatically inserted by the IDE, I just type it again and the cursor is out without actually keying in a duplicate quotation mark or parentheses. Isn't it the same in Netbeans? I'm not familiar with it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Type the second (end) quote. Netbeans realizes what's going on and does exactly what you describe.

Answer (score 0):

you should take the auto quotation as a help to minimaze errors:

"The user often writes a code that has opening and closing brackets, and this is very often source of compilation errors. If the IDE would insert a closing bracket each time opening bracket is typed, the likelihood of error is smaller, and the user also has a better visualization of the structure."

source: https://ui.netbeans.org/docs/hi/promoB/smartBrackets.html

I was looking to a "short cut" myself to allow me to jump outside the quotation even when the cursor is not at the end of the content, but I could not find it.

Like me, you might find this method useful as well: select the text you want to wrap in quotes/brackets and the press the opening quotes/brackets you like: NetBeans will do it for you.

source: [How to surround a text in quotes in netbeans IDE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9330207/how-to-surround-a-text-in-quotes-in-netbeans-ide/13731058)

code safe ;)