# How to surround a text in quotes in netbeans IDE

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-7

I have some text, say:

```
<td id=asd >
```

Is there a shortcut in  netbeans, where a selected text can be surrounded by quotes?

```
 <td id="asd" >
```

Answer (score 5):

If the macro is not there by default here is macro code that will accomplish what you want

```
caret-begin-word "'" caret-end-word "'"
```

or

```
caret-begin-word "\"" caret-end-word "\""
```

NOTE: This will only surround a WORD in quotes. Not your selection.

You can also highlight what you want and just hit `' or "` to surround the highlighted portion in quotes

Tested in NetBeans 7.2.1

Comment: Odd - I tried your last suggestion in 7.3, but I get the selected text replaced with the quote character I type. I'm editing a C file, though.

Answer (score 5):

As already suggested, there is a quote-word macro defined that will quote a single word.

To gain the ability to quote a selection:

1. Go to **Tools->Options->Editor->Macros**
2. Click [New] to create a new macro. Call it quote-selection, or whatever seems best to you.
3. Paste in the following macro:

   ```
   copy-to-clipboard "\"" paste-from-clipboard "\""
   ```
4. Click [Set Shortcut ...], then press your desired shortcut combination (eg. shift+ctrl+q)

Answer (score 3):

Go to

```
Tools->Options->Editor->Macros
```

and you will find a macro called `quote-word`

Just assign a shortcut to it and you can use it to surround a word with quotes.

Answer (score 1):

As of `NETBEANS IDE 8.2 :`

```
//i tried this on linux (debian)
```

**STEP 1:** First select "highlight" the text you want to be surrounded by quotes.
**STEP 2:**  Press   `Shift - "`

```
// Shift key and double quotes key
```

Hope this helps!!